# php bloack as3 after trying load variables in setinterval loop

Tags: php, actionscript-3, block

php bloack as3 after trying load variables in setinterval loop. i guess the title explain it all. actually i have flash widget that use URLLoader to grab some php variables and it works perfect but this urlloader is in setinterval loop that happens every 2 mins the problem is it work for several times well then after that php blocks the ip that loading the variables (using flash widget) and gives no response. i tried to search about this subject but found nothing especially that flash is outdated but i am using this flash in place which dont support except flash no js... idk what is the problem exactly but i got huge feeling its a server side issue and idk how to fix it. thought to share my issue here maybe someone can help. btw it blocks the ip of the user that been using the flash for long not for all but after 2-3 mins it unblocks the ip again and works again

btw when my ip is blocked by php i get this error as return by flash:

## 2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.

and by searching up found that this means the flash got nothing back from php request.

the as3 code is as simple as that:

```
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnDown);

function btnDown(event:MouseEvent):void {               
                    
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

var varto:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://url/dir/script.php");
varto.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varto.data = variables;
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
variables.somecode = "code";    
varLoader.load(varto);  
function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
var Var1fromphp = event.target.data.var1ofphp;
var Var2fromphp = event.target.data.var2ofphp;
from1_txt.text = Var1fromphp;
from2_txt.text = Var2fromphp;
trace("traced:" + event.target.data);

}   
                    
    }
```

thanks and appreciate all the replies/support

Comment: a code example would add helpful context

Comment: added the code example

Comment: Probably tweak the server so that it won't block the client IP after several requests in a row.

Comment: @WildLion I don't think that server is blocking you request which is sent every 2-3 minutes. Are you trying your code in a local server or an online one ? Could you show us your php code ? If your test is on an online server, is there a possibility to put the URL of your test ? ...

Answer (score 0):

found the problem wasnt php/server side its all about encoding then decoding the url for the variables cuz some vars had "&" character which interfer with the reponse.